# How to calculate the flux through a surface that is an intersection between a plane & cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

The surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is defined as the intersection of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ and the surface defined by $x^2 + z^2 = 1$, $z \geq 0$. The vector field $\mathbf{F} = (0, 0, x^2 + y^2)$.

Determine the surface integral $\iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{N} \, dS$, where $\mathbf{N}$ is the unit normal vector field on $S$ with a positive $z$-coordinate.

So I parametrized the curve using polar coordinates and got:
$$\vec{r} = \left(r\cos(t), r\sin(t), \sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2(t)}\right)$$
$$ 0 \leq r \leq 1$$
$$ 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$$
Then I differentiated with respect to t and r.
$$ r_{t} = (-r\sin(t), r\cos(t), \frac{r^2\sin(2t)}{2\sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2(t)}}$$
$$ r_{r} = (\cos(t), \sin(t), \frac{r^2\cos^(t)}{\sqrt{1-r^2\cos^2(t)}}$$

Then let a and b replace a complicated expression we will not need when we take the cross product between the partial derivatives.

$$\vec{n} = r_{t} \times r_{r} = (a, b, -r)$$
$$\vec{F} = (0,0,r^2)$$
Then I did:

$$\iint_{S} = (0, 0, r^2) \cdot (a, b, -r) dS = \iint_{S} -r^3 = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$

The correct answer is $\frac{\pi}2$, so why is my answer negative? Why am I wrong?

Comment: Your normal vector $n$ has the opposite orientation (the $z$ component is negative). See here the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4708114/difficulty-visualising-surfaces-and-translating-them-into-surface-integral

Comment: I suspected that was the problem too since the question states that the z coordinate of the normal vector should be positive. But I can't just change the sign of r just like that can I? I got this n by using cross product, so what if it doesn't satisfy it? The link you gave me is the same question but they did it in a different way which I understand. But I am just wondering why my way is not working.

Comment: "But I am just wondering why my way is not working". I told you: your parametrization induces the opposite orientation on the surface, hence you have to change the sign to your result. That's all.

Comment: I see a vertical cylinder volume and a horizontal half cylinder with y axis. Astigmatism?

Comment: @RobertZ Why does my parameterization induce opposite orientation? How do I know that?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Read my first comment carefully. Your normal is $\vec{n} = (a, b, -r)$. What is the sign of the $z$ component. What is the sign of the $z$ component in the problem's statement?

Comment: So they said that the orientation should be positive? And I got a negative orientation. But is it only the z component that determines which direction is negative or positive orientation?